# Hack: anymonious url on my joomla website

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, malware, phishing

My website has been hacked again. There are many foreign url such as [here](http://www.mentarimedia.com/stella-maris-college-chennai-application-form-_xuatn).

I've checked the database and there is nothing strange in my database. Does anyone know what kind of hacked attack like this?

Then I have to execute all files with exit (); and I quit "on /libraries/import.legacy.php".

If I give exit () under

```
JLoader :: register ('JRoute', JPATH_PLATFORM. '/joomla/application/route.php');
```

The result my website is still able to walk with the strange link.

but if I give exit() in the above

```
JLoader :: register ('JRoute', JPATH_PLATFORM. '/joomla/application/route.php')
```

The result is the website stops.

Comment: <=  http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AmitThakur. i will post to security.stackexchange.com to. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the newest version of Joomla? It's very important to keep a CMS updated as security issues are regularly discovered and patched. The same applies for all the extra plugins you're using.

Note that once your file system has been breached, it's very hard to make sure nothing else has been modified. You might think everything is clean, but you surely could have missed things. Often a clean install is the best option.

I'd suggest to find someone with experience in website security to find out what kind of attack is being used and how they have been using it. We don't have enough information to find out the problem for you.

Comment: i use git . if there are different would be found out. the script bypass the router.php to :-(.
ok thank you .. ^,^